# Getting the data inside a td tag using Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium Python. I am using Selenium for logging into a website. So far I have successfully logged in and navigated to the page I want. In that page I have a table with id "Common". Inside the table body I have a no. of table rows. I need to get a particular the value "234" from the table. Below is the rough look of the HTML. I need the value "234" to be printed in the output window. I am using Python 2.7. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<div id="Common" class="x6w" theme="medium">
<div id="Common::content" class="x108" theme="medium">
    <div>
        <div id="pf12" class="x19" theme="medium">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" summary="" role="presentation" style="width: auto">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="x4w" theme="medium" colspan="1">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" summary="" role="presentation">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr><td style="width: 150px"></td><td></td></tr>
                                        <tr>....</tr>
                                        <tr>....</tr>
                                        <tr class="13" theme="medium" id="15"><td class="13" theme="medium"><label class="label-text" theme="medium">ID</label></td><td valign="top" style="padding-left:9px" class="xv" theme="medium">234</td></tr>
```

Comment: I think you should elaborate more. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Ben I have edited my question, do you need anymore info?

Comment: Do you have any attempts of doing that? If yes, could you add those code snippets?

Comment: no @Ben I haven't tried that

Answer (score 1):

there is a authorisation error, in the html code

please provide the link for the page[Complte]

I you want to know how to iterate through elements [this code snippet from Github](https://github.com/manojap/wallspyder/blob/master/wallspyder/pexels.py) will help you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems related to locating an element.
You can do research on relative xpath

Anyways, base on your html, here's the locator using xpath

`targetElem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id,'Common')]//tbody/*[text()='ID']/parent::td/following-sibling::td") value = targetElem.text`

Answer (score 0):

For any webtable that you are accessing you should be able to extract the the td columns and for that you need to identify that way to make the unique locator like in the case above, you have text in between tags so you can xpath using javascript function "//*[text()='234]"
otherwise the id attribute can be used to extract that element and using the "text" function you can get the text printed on console.